# Save image in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation at work where people have to manually introduce pictures in a certain page of excel and resize it also manually. As a complete very beginner I've managed to find some VBA code to help introduce the picture by clicking a button and inserting it in a certain range of cells. The problem that I have is that I cannot figure out (after searching many posts) how to correctly introduce the function to save the image without making a link to it so others can see the report without getting an error that the picture doesn't exist.

Can you kindly help me and complete where the function should be introduced?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim objPic As Picture
Dim rngDest As Range
strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Images (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png),*.jpg;*.gif;*.png", _
    Title:="Please select an image...")
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set rngDest = Me.Range("B24:C26")
Set objPic = Me.Pictures.Insert(strFileName)
With objPic
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Left = rngDest.Left
    .Top = rngDest.Top
    .Width = rngDest.Width
    .Height = rngDest.Height
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this and it gives me an error saying "run-time error '448', named argument not found.

Comment: `Set objPic = Me.Pictures.Insert(strFileName)` is correct. It should insert the image without making it a link. You can also use [Shapes.AddPicture method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addpicture). Something like `Dim objPic As Object` and then in the next line `Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(strFileName, False, True, 10, 10, -1, -1)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you very much. I've made the test with your suggestion two computers and it works ! I wish you a really good day :) 
For others to know ,I've deleted this line since it was giving an error and added the activesheet as Siddharth said.
`code` ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

Comment: If you are running the code from the sheet module then you can continue using `Me` but if you are running this code from a userform then you should declare your worksheet object and use that. For example `Dim ws as Worksheet` and then `Set ws = Sheet1` and finally `Set objPic = ws.Shapes.AddPicture....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Shape '<<<
    Dim rngDest As Range
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Images (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png),*.jpg;*.gif;*.png", _
        Title:="Please select an image...")
    If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Set rngDest = Me.Range("B24:C26")

     Set objPic = Me.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=strFileName, _
                                       linktofile:=msoFalse, _
                                       savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
                                       Left:=rngDest.Left, Top:=rngDest.Top, _
                                       Width:=rngDest.Width, Height:=rngDest.Height)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you also very much for your help, I made the test like Siddharth said and it worked. Hopefully in the future someone will see this codes and it will help them.